# How from one fragment start method in another?

Tags: android, fragment

In fragment A i have functionality to retrivive url
In fragment B i have functionality to proceed and display url.

how fragment A can tell to fragment B that there is new data to proceed, where 2 fragments are placed side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define an interface and call a method in the interface. The other fragment will implement that interface and when the method gets called you will call the method the you need.

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

This is an approch that I would suggest. In my scenario FragmentA is the one calling your method and FragmentB is the one that contains the method.

Define this interface in your fragmentA

```
public interface FragmentContainer {
    void onMethodThatYouWantToBeFired();
}
```

In the onAttach, do something like that:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Fragment parentFragment = getParentFragment();
    if (parentFragment == null) {
        mFragmentContainer = (FragmentContainer) activity;
    } else {
        mFragmentContainer = (FragmentContainer) parentFragment;
    }
}
```

Let your activity implements YourFragment.FragmentContainer and override the method void onMethodThatYouWantToBeFired();
When this method is fired call a listener registered in FragmentB. When the listener is fired, then you can call the method in FragmentB that you are interested in.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: and there is a problem, which i cannot solve. Fragment B implements listener and this part is simple. But how fragment A initialise the listener and thus use it method?

Comment: You should use your activity to allow your fragment to communicate to each other.

Comment: I wrote an outline how I would implement your scenario. I hope it could be useful for you.

Comment: The whole problem is that both fragments are completly independet from each other, except the communication i want to make.  They are both started by activity at same time. And they run in same time

Comment: That's fine....your activity receive callback from FragmentA and forward it to FragmentB through interfaces and FragmentB fires the method you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are meant to be re-used... that is, two fragments should not directly pass data between each other. Instead, you should define a [callback method](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) in the Activity. This will ensure that you can re-use your fragments elsewhere in your app (and in other apps you make) if you need to.

Comment: Re using, that exactly why I am interested in comunication. I want to update data instead of recreating fragment.

Comment: You can use Bundle to pass data between them if you want. There's already a thread on this here. Google it.

Comment: I dont need to path data, i need to call method

Comment: Then just call the method from when you inflated the fragment.

Comment: Somehow I have feling that you believe that fragment B was started by fragment A...